# std::thread: Timed Join

Tags: multithreading, c++11, join

I am writing a multithreaded application. In one section, a thread will be deleted. I want to give the Thread time for cleaning up everything, but there might be a point, where the thread waits for userdata and blocks. I want to join the thread, if thats not possible within X seconds, it shall be deleted. How can I achieve this with C++11 without using boost? I know boost hast try_join_for, but std::thread seems not to have this function.

Code for better understanding:

```
while (clientRunning) {
    char data[8192];
    recv(sockfd,data,8192,MSG_WAITALL);
}
```

This function is inside a thread (reduced to a minimum). And now i want to join this thread using thread->join(); and have that join a timeout, so it will try to join for lets say 2 Minutes, if that does not happen, it shall terminate the thread by force.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I dont know how code could be helpful here. I have a thread in a while loop with a blocking function (recv) in it, Ill edit my post with some little code...

Comment: @Nidhoegger Any news? I need something similar for more than 1 thread!

Comment: Yes and no. Basically what I started to do is not use recv to wait for the socket but use `epoll` or `select` instead. When you invoke a `SIGCHLD` signal when epoll and select will get interrupted and return `EINTR` as `errno`. That way I know now that the thread got interrupted and wants to join. But you have to be VERY careful, if your process uses `fork` or similar mechanism, you will get the `SIGCHLD` signal for some other reasons (child process quits and needs cleanup). But be aware that this will only work on *nix systems (on windows you could use `WaitForSingleObject` i think)

Answer (score 0):

## 1. In C++ you cannot delete a running thread

If you try to, the result would almost always be undefined: mutexes that the thread holds will not be released, memory that it owns will not be freed, the list goes on.

The solution usually is to design your thread such that it periodically checks if it needs to continue running. In your example, you would replace the blocking `recv()` with a non-blocking one, such that you can check some flag to see if you need to abort or continue.

This flag is usually passed to the thread in the form of a so-called cancellation token. See `std::stop_token` and `std::jthread` for some support of that in the standard library.

Boost has some support for interrupting threads. It is basically the same mechanism under the covers. Your code has to periodically call `this_thread::interruption_point()`, and if you previously called `thread::interrupt()`, then that'll throw an exception, terminating your thread.

But whichever way you go, you have to implement some mechanism for making the thread stop voluntarily, and only then can it be successfully joined/deleted.

## 2. The C++ standard library doesn't have support for `timed_join()`

I'm not sure why it was omitted, except to say that if you manage to successfully cancel your thread, your `join()` will always succeed and therefore `timed_join()` is unnecessary.

Of course code could be buggy, and I have in the past used `timed_join()` to write a message to the log that we're waiting for some thread to stop (which is the only sane thing you can do when a thread refuses to voluntarily terminate). If I had to do something like that using only the standard library, then I'd probably wrap the function that the thread is executing in a `std::packaged_task<void()>` or similar, and then do a `wait_for()` on the resulting `std::future`. Once that succeeds, you know the thread has finished, and the `thread::join()` will return (nearly) immediately.

Come to think of it: wrapping stuff in a `std::packaged_task`, starting a thread and returning a `std::future` is done pretty neatly by `std::async`, so I'd probably use that.